# Circuitikz: I can't put the equal sign inside the names

Tags: circuitikz

I substituted the equal signs I want with arrows in the labels. How can I have equals signs there?

I want to put the same and the cable jump. I don't know how to use it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin {circuitikz} [american]
\draw


(0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}

(opamp.-) to[short,-] ++(-1,0)
to [R, l_=$1K\Omega$] ++(-2,0)
to [V, l_=$B_3\rightarrow 1v$] ++(0,-4)
to node[ground]{} ++(0,0)

(opamp.-) to [short, *-] ++(0,3) 
 to [short, -] ++(2,0) 
to [R, l_=$2K \Omega$] (3,3.5)
to [short,-] ++(1,0)
to[short, -*] ++(0,-3.5)
(opamp.out) to [short, -o]++ (4,0) node[right]{$V_o$}

(opamp.+) -| ++(0,-3) node[ground]{}

(opamp.up) to [short, -]  ++(0,5)
to [short, -] ++(8,0)
to [V,l_=$B_3 \rightarrow 15v$] ++(0,-4) 

to [V,l_=$B_2 \rightarrow 15 v$] (8,-3) 
 to[short,-] (8,-3) coordinate (leftC)
  to (leftC -| opamp.down)
  to[short,-] (opamp.down)
(8,0)[short,*-] (7.9,2) to node[ground]{} (10,2)
;

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unrelated: You should really consider using `siunitx` to typeset your units! `1K\Omega` is no correct typography for units, first of all, the kilo prefix is a small k, second it shouldn't be italic but upright, and there should be a small space between the `1` and the `k`. With the `siunitx` option you could use `R=1<\kilo\ohm>` and would get pretty results.

Comment: Also: Which arrows are missing?

Comment: You can't use a `=` directly. It's in the manual, around page 132, "Caveat:".  It's a mix of a `circuitikz` problem and the Ti*k*Z parser. Use `l_=\mbox{$B_3=\SI{15}{V}$}` for example (using `siunitx` package, you units are typed wrong --- they should be uprigt)

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz I edited the question in the sense I understand it. But still I can't grasp what the OP wants with "I want to put the same"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a pair of braces `{}` around the labels and, as people here suggested, you can free yourself from correct formatting the units by virtue of `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin {circuitikz} [american]
\draw


(0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}

(opamp.-) to[short,-] ++(-1,0)
to [R, l_=${R_1=\SI{1}{\kohm}}$] ++(-2,0)
to [V, l_=${B_1=\SI{1}{V}}$] ++(0,-4)
to node[ground]{} ++(0,0)

(opamp.-) to [short, *-] ++(0,3) 
 to [short, -] ++(2,0) 
to [R, l_=${R_2=\SI{2}{\kohm}}$] (3,3.5)
to [short,-] ++(1,0)
to[short, -*] ++(0,-3.5)
(opamp.out) to [short, -o]++ (4,0) node[right]{$V_o$}

(opamp.+) -| ++(0,-3) node[ground]{}

(opamp.up) to [short, -]  ++(0,5)
to [short, -] ++(8,0)
to [V,l_=${B_3=\SI{15}{V}}$] ++(0,-4) 

to [V,l_=${B_2=\SI{15}{V}}$] (8,-3) 
 to[short,-] (8,-3) coordinate (leftC)
  to (leftC -| opamp.down)
  to[short,-] (opamp.down)
(8,0)[short,*-] (7.9,2) to node[ground]{} (10,2)
;

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Correct here, but using just `{}` could fail (and this *is definitely* a bug in `circuitikz`, see https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/346), because we do not put back the braces stripped by the Ti*k*Z parser passing the argument... Better use `\mbox{...}`

Comment: Whatever, the braces work fine for me and I didn't hit any problems using them.

Comment: ;-) yes in this case is ok. But try `to [R, l_=\SI{1}{\kohm}, v={$v=0$}] ++(-2,0)` and it'll explode...

Answer (score 2):

In the manual, you can read (at the start of the chapter about labels):

[image]

This is one possible solution (I really would avoid the jump crossing, it's clear that there is no connection here, and students should learn the normal way to draw circuits; moreover, I am using a correct printing of units here):

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.78pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[EFvoltages, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin {circuitikz} [american]
\def\eq{=}
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}

(opamp.-) to[short,-] ++(-1,0)
to [R, l_=\SI{1}{\kohm}] ++(-2,0)
to [V, l_=$B_3\eq\SI{1}{V}$] ++(0,-4)
to node[ground]{} ++(0,0)

(opamp.-) to [short, *-] ++(0,3)
 to [short, -] ++(2,0)
 to [R, l_=\SI{2}{\kohm}] (3,3.5)
to [short,-] ++(1,0)
to[short, -*] ++(0,-3.5)
(opamp.out) to [short, -o]++ (4,0) node[right]{$V_o$}

(opamp.+) -| ++(0,-3) node[ground]{}

(opamp.up) to [short, -]  ++(0,5)
to [short, -] ++(8,0)
to [V,l_=$B_3 \eq \SI{15}{V}$] ++(0,-4)

to [V,l_=$B_2 \eq \SI{15}{V}$] (8,-3)
 to[short,-] (8,-3) coordinate (leftC)
  to (leftC -| opamp.down)
  to[short,-] (opamp.down)
(8,0)[short,*-] (7.9,2) to node[ground]{} (10,2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]